# Laravel 5.5 - automatically logging user out on redirect (on server, but does not do this locally)

Tags: php, facebook-login, laravel-5.5, laravel-socialite, laravel-authentication

I am trying to create an app that does nothing besides log a user in through the Socialite plugin. 
Everything is working fine, I am redirected to facebook, the new user is created, and then when the user is redirected to '/', the user is mysteriously logged out.

(Note, this doesn't happen locally. On my local machine everything works fine).

Facebook Login Controller:

```
public function handleFacebookCallback()
{
    $socialiteUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

    $user = $this->findOrCreateUser('facebook', $socialiteUser);

    Auth::login($user, true);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Routes file:

```
Route::get('/', 'Home@home')->name('home')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/home', 'Home@home')->name('home')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/login', 'Controller@welcome')->name('welcome');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::get('facebook', function() {
    return view('facebook');
});
Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\FacebookController@redirectToFacebook');
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'Auth\FacebookController@handleFacebookCallback');
```

Login Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

There is no defined "auth" middleware in my middlewares folder. It is done automatically through laravel.

AGAIN: this project works as intended LOCALLY, but not on the server.

final note: when I dd(Auth::check()) IMMEDIATELY before redirecting to '/', even on the server, I get "true", but then when I dd the same thing on the login page i get false. So somehow the user is being logged out on the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem `Route::get('/', 'Home@home')->name('home')->middleware('auth');`

You are using auth middleware in your \ path.
If you don't know what does that middleware do i recommend you this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#protecting-routes

Your route should be

```
Route::get('/', 'Home@home')->name('home');
```

But you should modify this too, becouse they are using the same controller

```
Route::get('/home', 'Home@home')->name('home')->middleware('auth');
```

**Another solution could be checking the URL's at developer facebook page.**

Comment: So you should not use a middleware on your '/' path?

Comment: Making these changes did not solve the issue. As mentioned it works locally, but on the server I am logged out immediately upon redirect.

Comment: I was purposely using auth middleware in my / path, because I don't want anything accessed unless the user is logged in.

Comment: you did not mention that on the post. be clear. show the auth controller and middleware

Comment: as it works locally, and not in the server, might be some configuration in the developer tab at facebook, did you add your new url to the accepted ones?

Comment: Yes I did, it ended up being an issue with the session domain variable set. I had to remove it and let it grab the null default back up value and it fixed my issue.